# Error mounting SD card when returning from suspend

Tags: mount, suspend, thinkpad, automount, sd-card

I have a 128 GB SD card that I use for permanent storage in my Lenovo Thinkpad X1. I've mounted it in /etc/fstab with this line:

```
UUID=37733366-e936-41df-983a-f084352b3a5b   /home/kristian/sd128gb  auto    defaults 0  0
```

which works just fine. Until I put my machine to suspend, upon returning I get the error:

```
Error mounting system-managed device /dev/mmcblk0p1: Command-line
`mount "/home/kristian/sd128gb"' exited with non-zero exit status 32:
mount: File exists
```

The mount point directory is empty, but attempting to mount it gives

```
$ mount sd128gb/
mount: according to mtab, /dev/mmcblk0p1 is already mounted on /home/kristian/sd128gb
```

Syslog gives

```
kernel: [271462.070388] EXT4-fs warning (device mmcblk0p1): __ext4_read_dirblock:908: error reading directory block (ino 2, block 0)
kernel: [271462.070410] EXT4-fs warning (device mmcblk0p1): __ext4_read_dirblock:908: error reading directory block (ino 2, block 0)
kernel: [271462.091100] EXT4-fs warning (device mmcblk0p1): __ext4_read_dirblock:908: error reading directory block (ino 2, block 0)
kernel: [271462.091130] EXT4-fs warning (device mmcblk0p1): __ext4_read_dirblock:908: error reading directory block (ino 2, block 0)
```

Unmounting and mounting it again works, but this is a hassle to do every time I return from suspend -- especially as I use it for permanent storage, it doesn't feel very reliable to work with data on a partition that frequently unmounts.

The "file exists" message seems obscure, and googling it, it seems like not many people get the same error message.

Can I fix this permanently? Or, alternatively: How could I make an ugly fix with a remount command that runs every time I return from suspend?

Comment: This is possibly related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/505779/suspending-with-root-on-usb

Answer (score 0):

In case you're looking for an answer to this `remount read-only` issue, an [unRaid valuable article](https://lime-technology.com/wiki/index.php/The_Analysis_of_Drive_Issues) showed me the solution yesterday, after I had a very similar issue on my biggest hard drive (while already recovering the files of an silly USB key...)

My logs:

```
[40860.074298] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 104869128
[40860.074306] EXT4-fs warning (device sdc2): __ext4_read_dirblock:884: error -5 reading directory block (ino 2, block 0)
[40860.661232] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] UNKNOWN Result: hostbyte=0x04 driverbyte=0x00
[40860.661237] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB:
[40860.661239] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 06 40 2d 08 00 00 08 00
```

However, the most interesting error was before these, ie the first or second line related to this issue:

```
mars 27 22:27:55 llewellyn kernel: ata8: SError: { PHYRdyChg CommWake 10B8B LinkSeq }
```

### Heading

Looking for `PHYRdyChg` on [mentionned article](https://lime-technology.com/wiki/index.php/The_Analysis_of_Drive_Issues), guided me to the « Drive interface issue #4 », ruling out any hard drive failure or driver issue :) Quoting their explanation:

« This is an example of what is probably a loose backplane or cable connection issue: (could be either the SATA connection or the power connection or both)

```
ata7.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x7 SErr 0x990000 action 0xa frozen
ata7.00: irq_stat 0x00400000, PHY RDY changed
ata7: SError: { PHYRdyChg 10B8B Dispar LinkSeq }
ata7.00: cmd 60/48:00:af:1b:97/00:00:10:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 36864 in
           res 40/00:10:87:5f:96/00:00:10:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
ata7.00: status: { DRDY }
```

Note: There are no CRC errors here, which normally implicate a bad cable or two. »

I checked any Sata / Power cables, rebooted and all was fine. A `smartctl -a -A /dev/sdc` confirmed this.

PS: The unRAID article is invaluable to understand various Hard Drive errors and messages (eg `BadCRC`, `failed to recover`).